# How to install Tomcat 8 on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty LTS using the “apt-get” way?

Tags: 14.04, tomcat

I've already installed java8 on this server, then I want to install tomcat8 using the "apt-get" way(not the binary way).But After lots of googling,I can't find the solution，most of the solutions are using the binary way(download the apache-tomcat-8.X.X.tar.gz,then unzip it and start the tomcat...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat 8 is not in the repositories for Ubuntu 14.04. 
You could install Tomcat 7, as this is in the repositories, by running `sudo apt-get install tomcat7`.

Comment: yes,I can't find it too.Thanks for your answer:)

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat8 is now present in the repositories and can be installed using this `aptitude` command:

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat8
```

Comment: It's not in mine. Are you sure you're running 14.04?

Comment: It is not in trusty repositories as of now.

Comment: Still not in trusty as of Jan 9 '17